# Led lights on sensors

Tags: electrical-distribution

Have changed can lights to led, have some on motion sensors. The one on motion sensors stay very dim light after sensor turns them off is this a problem?

Answer (score 1):

For the obsolete type of sensor you are using, you're doing better than many.

There are two ways a sensor can get power.   One is to bring a hot and neutral wire to the sensor location.  However, many sensors are retrofitted where a plain switch had been, and  plain switches do not require a neutral wire, so there isn't one.

So the other type was developed.  It gets power by leaking a small amount of power through the entire circuit, including the lamps.   Thats not enough to light up an old incandescent bulb.  But it is enough to light some LEDs since they are so efficient.

You are probably stuck with it unless you switch to the other motion-sensor type. Or make one of your bulbs incandescent.

Comment: I agree if there is a neutral in the switch box you could upgrade to a new motion sensor.

Comment: Could this be a safety issue?

Comment: Unlikely. Any older dimmer works the same way - by leaking current in this manner.  An LED not listed to work on dimmers, remote chance it might have a problem being driven in this way.  But one *listed* for use with dimmers should be fine.